# How to access elements from a certain form and certain type with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

so I have a page with multiple forms and I would like to be able to access input elements of `type="datetime"` within a particular form. I know I can do `$('input[type="datetime"]')` but that would give me all input tags on the page. I also cannot use the "form" attribute because not all browser use it (Sigh IE). Worse scenario for me is to do something like:

```
$(document.forms["..."].elements).each(function() {
    if (this.type="datetime") {.....}
});
```

but I am sure this can be done in jQuery with one selector. Can someone tell me how do this with one selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it

Solution 1.
use [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)
ex:

```
$('#yourform input[type="datetime"]') //or
$('.yourform input[type="datetime"]') //or
$('form:eq(3) input[type="datetime"]')
```

Solution 2:
Use [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) based look up
Ex:

```
$('input[type="datetime"]', yourform)
```

Comment: thanks for context lookup solutions as well.  Is the a reason to use the context over the descendant formula - such as performance?

Comment: Looks like context bases look up is faster http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-context-vs-descendant-selector

Comment: Thanks for the insight - turns out the descendant selector is actually the slowest and that made me go with context based look up.

Answer (score 3):

Add id to your form and then select DOM inside of that form as below.

```
$('#form input[type="datetime"]')
```

Comment: yeah - embarrassing I overlooked that.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing some HTML this is just a shot in the dark.  But if you give your forms an id you can do:

```
$("#yourFormId input[type='datetime']");
```

If you do not have ids, but you know the number, then this might do it:

```
$("form:eq(4) input[type='datetime']");
```